# ERROR 1451 Cannot delete a record from parent table

Tags: mysql

Hey guys so im trying to delete a record. However doesnt allow me due to a foreign key constraint

Operation im trying to perform is 
(all cards numbers are fake)

```
DELETE FROM payment_method
WHERE card_no = 42218345;
```

table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE  payment_details  (
   card_no  int(8) NOT NULL,
   customer_id  int(50)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   CVV  int(3) NOT NULL,
   card_type  ENUM ('Visa', 'Amex', 'American Express', 'Mastercard') NOT NULL,
   expiry_date  DATE NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(card_no),
   KEY customer_idfk1 (customer_id),
   CONSTRAINT customer_idfk1 FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE  customers  (
   customer_id  int(50)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   fname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   lname  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   dateOfBirth date NOT NULL,
   address  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
   city  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   county  ENUM('Armagh','Carlow','Cavan','Clare','Cork','Derry','Donegal','Down','Dublin','Fermanagh','Galway','Kerry','Kildare','Kilkenny','Laois','Leitrim','Limerick','Longford','Louth','Mayo','Meath','Monaghan','Offaly','Roscommon','Sligo','Tipperary','Tyrone','Waterford','Westmeath','Wexford','Wicklow') NOT NULL,
   phone  int(10) NOT NULL,
   email  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
   payment_method  ENUM ('Visa', 'Amex', 'Cash', 'American Express', 'Mastercard') NOT NULL,
   valid_licence varchar(5) NOT NULL,
   status  varchar(10),
   PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

error is:

> ## 1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`g00337857abu`.`payment_details`, CONSTRAINT `customer_idfk1`
>
> FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customer_id`))

Does anyone know Why it doesnt allow me to delete this record..

**Ive spotted 1st error**

Now im trying to delete from customers table

```
DELETE FROM customers
WHERE customer_id = 1
```

> error  - #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`g00337857abu`.`payment_details`, CONSTRAINT
>   `customer_idfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers`
>   (`customer_id`))

Comment: What is `payment_method`? A third table?

Comment: Actually i just spotted that. No its not. its supposed to show a payment from payment_details tbl - what do you recommend to do

Comment: What table are you deleting from?

Comment: payment_details

Comment: Look at your code.

Comment: Do not post details in the comments. Add them (using [Edit]) to your question.

Comment: done, still need a hand on it

Comment: You need to learn what `FOREIGN KEY` CONSTRAINT is and about *referential integrity*.

Comment: sir, could you suggest any possible solution? I would highly appreciate it.